# Insert multiple rows with same unique ID

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting multiple rows using one query and, obviously, the ID column auto increments each row. I want to create another ID column and have the ID remain the same for all rows inserted during the query. So if I insert 10 rows during one query, I want all 10 rows to have the id "1". How can this be done? Thanks for any help

Comment: I don't get the question. What's stopping you from just making another column and keeping the value in it the same in all 10 inserts?

Comment: Are you saying you want to add a second column, for example: `secondaryId`, and have this be the same for all records inserted? or you want the `primaryId` to be the same (which is not possible).

Comment: Why would you make the column auto_increment if you don't want it to auto increment?

Comment: @ExplosionPills primaryId is auto increment as each row/item needs its' own id. I would like a secondaryId that is the same for all rows inserted during one query.

Comment: @SOfanatic Correct. I would like a secondaryId and have this be the same for all rows inserted during one query. The id would need to increase by 1 for each query performed.

Comment: @Alex then JW's answer would work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to supply an `ID` for the specific group of `INSERT` statements.

Assumming you have this schema

```
CREATE TABLE TableName
(
    RecordID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    OtherColumn VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    GroupID INT NOT NULL
)
```

You can have two statements for this:

1.) Getting the last `GroupID` and increment it by `1`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(GroupID), 0) + 1 AS newGroupID FROM TableName
```

2.) once you have executed it, store the value in a variable. Use this variable for all the insert statement,

```
$groupID = row['newGroupID'];
$insert1 = "INSERT INTO TableName(OtherColumn, GroupID) VALUES ('a', $groupID)";
$insert2 = "INSERT INTO TableName(OtherColumn, GroupID) VALUES ('b', $groupID)";
$insert3 = "INSERT INTO TableName(OtherColumn, GroupID) VALUES ('c', $groupID)";
```

**UPDATE 1**

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/285e1/1)