# Insert data one by one to database but have same unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to ask. Is it possible if i am insert data to my database one by one, but have same a unique ID to show that all data that i have inserted is a ONE data. Like

```
id_primary   |   name   |   unique_id
     1       |   test1  |      001
     2       |   test2  |      001
     3       |   test3  |      001
     4       |   test4  |      001
     5       |   bobo   |      002
     6       |   bebe   |      002
```

Maybe someone can give me some advice.. Thank you and have a nice day. Cheerss!!

Comment: Just insert common records with the same `unique_id` ... is there an actual question here?

Comment: i am just insert name, id_primary (auto increment), and then i don't know how to set unique id (unique id automatically set)

Comment: Then maybe the question actually lies in your application logic.  Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Honestly i am really confused about the logic to have same unique id in multiple insert

Comment: It's more like a batch id than a unique id and you would have to code for it ,possibly involving a table to hold the last batch id number.

Comment: You have some constraint that prevents setting the unique_id?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: > http://stackoverflow.com/q/16138432/7012517
you should visit this question

Comment: Please work on your naming skills. If the column values are not unique, don't call it Unique_Id (or Id, for that matter). Call it Group_Id or something along these lines to convey the actual meaning of the column.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the procedure to get the maximum existing unique_id, then increment it and use the value in insert.

```
declare @uniqueIdVal int
declare @uniqueId varchar(3)

select @uniqueIdVal = isnull(max(convert(int, unique_id)), 0) + 1 
from datatable

set @uniqueId = right('000' + convert(varchar(3), @uniqueIdVal), 3)

insert into datatable (name, unique_id)
values ('name1', @uniqueId),
       ('name2', @uniqueId),
       ...
       ('nameN', @uniqueId)
```

But I'm not quite sure if this is the problem here

Comment: sorry sir, i am input from my web page, php using sqlsrv. How to implement it? any thoughts,idea or advice ?

Comment: So you send the select command to get the max value in the first request, then in the second one send the insert command. I do not know the php, but it would be good to make both the request in one transaction to lock the table and avoid the concurrent conflicting inserts.

Comment: PHP is not even tagged. Please add the php code and tag the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in MS sql server, the field unique_id should be set as Integer.

```
DECLARE @maxUniqueId int

SELECT @maxUniqueId = NVL(MAX(unique_id), 0) FROM table_name;

set @maxUniqueId = maxUniqueId + 1;

insert into table (name, unique_id) values ('xxx', maxUniqueId);
insert into table (name, unique_id) values ('xxx', maxUniqueId);
insert into table (name, unique_id) values ('xxx', maxUniqueId);
```